# Angular Movie Service with Firebase Problem

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from firebase using this movie service.

My database with collection name movies has the following data:

```js
 export const MOVIES: any = {

    1: {
        id: 1,
        title: 'The Crown Hunters',
        season: 'Season 1',
        overview: 'Three Young Men were sent to search for a lost Crown, but unknown to them that the crown could only be recovered by unknown identity',
        poster_path: '/The_Crown_Hunters_SmallEpisode1',
        posterUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SmartsSmallPoster/The_Crown_Hunters_SmallEpisode1.png',
        backdropUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/BigBackdrop/The_Crown_Hunters_BigPoster.jpg',
        adult: false,
        genre_ids: [
        21, 29, 31
      ],
        backdrop_path: '/The_Crown_Hunters_BigPoster.jpg',
        member_required: true,
        free: false,
        belongs_to_collection: 'movies',
        original_language: 'en',
        popularity: '225',
        vote_count: '3900',
        video: false,
        vote_average: '7.5',
        homepage: '',
        imdb_id: 'aef091076',
        credit_ids: ['52fe43c4c3a36847f806e20d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e21d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e22d', 
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e23d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e24d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e25d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e26d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e27d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e28d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e29d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e30d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e31d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e32d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e33d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e34d'  
       ],
       cast_ids: [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       production_companies: '3smartsflix',
       production_countries: 'NG',
       runtime: '15',
       spoken_languages: 'en',
       status: 'Released',
       release_type: 2,
       category: 'now_playing',
       now_playing: true,
       upcoming: false,
       category_id: 85,
       tagline: 'Hunters Never Quit',
       file_path: '/3smarts-photo-backdrops',
       movieId: 55,
       recomend_id: '',
       categories: ['TRENDING'],
       seqNo: 0,
       url: 'the-journey-part1',
    },

    2: {
        id: 2,
        movieId: 55,
        title: 'The Crown Hunters',
        season: 'Season 1',
        episode: 'Episode 2',
        episode_title: 'Episode Title: The Journey Part II',
        overview: 'Three Young Men were sent to search for a lost Crown, but unknown to them that the crown could only be recovered by unknown identity',
        poster_path: '/The_Crown_Hunters_SmallEpisode2',
        posterUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SmartsSmallPoster/The_Crown_Hunters_SmallEpisode2.png',
        backdropUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/BigBackdrop/The_Crown_Hunters_BigPoster.jpg',
        adult: false,
        release_date: '21st August, 2021',
        genre_ids: [
        21, 29, 31
      ],
       backdrop_path: '/The_Crown_Hunters_BigPoster.jpg',
       member_required: true,
       free: false,
       belongs_to_collection: null,
       original_language: 'en',
       popularity: null,
       vote_count: '4200',
       video: false,
       vote_average: '7.7',
       homepage: '',
       imdb_id: 'aef091076',
       credit_ids: ['52fe43c4c3a36847f806e20d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e21d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e22d', 
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e23d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e24d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e25d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e26d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e27d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e28d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e29d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e30d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e31d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e32d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e33d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e34d'  
       ],
       cast_ids: [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       production_companies: '3smartsflix',
       production_countries: 'NG',
       runtime: '15',
       spoken_languages: 'en',
       status: 'Released',
       release_type: 2,
       category: 'now_playing',
       now_playing: true,
       upcoming: false,
       category_id: 85,
       tagline: 'Hunters Never Quit',
       file_path: '/3smarts-photo-backdrops',
       recomend_id: ['aef091076' ],
       categories: ['TRENDING'],
       seqNo: 2,
       url: 'the-journey-part2',
       backdrops: ''
    },

    3: {
        id: 3,
        movieId: 55,
        title: 'The Crown Hunters',
        season: 'Season 1',
        episode: 'Episode 3',
        episode_title: 'The Throne Part I',
        overview: 'Three Young Men were sent to search for a lost Crown, but unknown to them that the crown could only be recovered by unknown identity',
        poster_path: '/The_Crown_Hunters_SmallEpisode3',
        posterUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SmartsSmallPoster/The_Crown_Hunters_SmallEpisode3.png',
        backdropUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/BigBackdrop/The_Crown_Hunters_BigPoster.jpg',
        adult: false,
        release_date: '1st Dec, 2021',
        genre_ids: [
        21, 29, 31
      ],
       backdrop_path: '/The_Crown_Hunters_BigPoster.jpg',
       member_required: true,
       free: false,
       belongs_to_collection: null,
       original_language: 'en',
       popularity: null,
       vote_count: '4300',
       video: false,
       vote_average: '7.8',
       homepage: '',
       imdb_id: 'aef091076',
       credit_ids: ['52fe43c4c3a36847f806e20d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e21d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e22d', 
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e23d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e24d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e25d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e26d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e27d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e28d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e29d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e30d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e31d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e32d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e33d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e34d'  
       ],
       cast_ids: [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       production_companies: '3smartsflix',
       production_countries: 'NG',
       runtime: '15',
       spoken_languages: 'en',
       status: 'Released',
       release_type: 2,
       category: 'now_playing',
       now_playing: true,
       upcoming: false,
       category_id: 85,
       tagline: 'Hunters Never Quit',
       file_path: '/3smarts-photo-backdrops',
       recomend_id: [1, 2, 4 ],
       categories: ['TRENDING'],
       seqNo: 3,
       url: 'the-journey-part3',
    },

    4: {
        id: 4,
        movieId: 55,
        title: 'The Crown Hunters',
        season: 'Season 1',
        episode: 'Episode 4',
        episode_title: 'Episode Title: The Throne Part II',
        overview: 'Three Young Men were sent to search for a lost Crown, but unknown to them that the crown could only be recovered by unknown identity',
        poster_path: '/The_Crown_Hunters_SmallEpisode4',
        posterUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SmartsSmallPoster/The_Crown_Hunters_SmallEpisode4.png',
        backdropUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/BigBackdrop/The_Crown_Hunters_BigPoster.jpg',
        adult: false,
        release_date: '15th Dec, 2021',
        genre_ids: [
        21, 29, 31
      ],
       backdrop_path: '/The_Crown_Hunters_BigPoster.jpg',
       member_required: true,
       free: false,
       belongs_to_collection: null,
       original_language: 'en',
       popularity: null,
       vote_count: '4400',
       video: false,
       vote_average: '7.9',
       homepage: '',
       imdb_id: 'aef091076',
       credit_ids: ['52fe43c4c3a36847f806e20d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e21d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e22d', 
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e23d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e24d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e25d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e26d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e27d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e28d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e29d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e30d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e31d',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e32d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e33d', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806e34d'  
       ],
       cast_ids: [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       production_companies: '3smartsflix',
       production_countries: 'NG',
       runtime: '15',
       spoken_languages: 'en',
       status: 'Released',
       release_type: 2,
       category: 'now_playing',
       now_playing: true,
       upcoming: false,
       category_id: 85,
       tagline: 'Hunters Never Quit',
       file_path: '/3smarts-photo-backdrops',
       recomend_id: [1, 2, 3 ],
       categories: ['TRENDING'],
       seqNo: 4,
       url: 'the-journey-part4',
    },

    5: {
        id: 5,
        movieId: 66,
        title: 'The Rich Master and The Donkeys',
        season: 'Season 1',
        episode: 'Episode 1',
        episode_title: 'Episode Title: The Man of Wisdom I',
        overview: 'The Donkeys thought thier minds are hidden but unknowing to them that it goes beyond the physical and that there is one who dwells among them and He knows and sees everything beyond the physical',
        poster_path: '/The_RichMaster_SmallEpisode1.png',
        posterUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SmartsSmallPoster/The_RichMaster_SmallEpisode1.png',
        backdropUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/BigBackdrop/The_RichMaster_BigPoster.jpg',
        adult: false,
        release_date: '3rd March, 2022',
        genre_ids: [
        27, 28, 31
      ],
       backdrop_path: '/The_RichMaster_BigPoster.jpg',
       member_required: true,
       free: false,
       belongs_to_collection: null,
       original_language: 'en',
       popularity: 230,
       vote_count: '4300',
       video: false,
       vote_average: '8.1',
       homepage: '',
       imdb_id: 'aef091080',
       credit_ids: ['52fe43c4c3a36847f807y890', '52fe43c4c3a36847f808y891', '52fe43c4c3a36847f809y892', 
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f801y893', '52fe43c4c3a36847f802y894', '52fe43c4c3a36847f803y895',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f804y896', '52fe43c4c3a36847f805y897', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806y898',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f801z899'
                      
       ],
       cast_ids: [
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       production_companies: '3smartsflix',
       production_countries: 'NG',
       runtime: '15',
       spoken_languages: 'en',
       status: 'Upcoming',
       release_type: 3,
       category: 'upcoming',
       upcoming: true,
       now_playing: false,
       category_id: 86,
       tagline: 'Purge Your Mind To House The Goodluck',
       file_path: '/3smarts-photorichmaster-backdrops',
       recomend_id: [6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       categories: ['UPCOMING'],
       seqNo: 5,
       url: 'the-man-of-wisdom1',
    },

    6: {
        id: 6,
        movieId: 66,
        title: 'The Rich Master & The Donkeys',
        season: 'Season 1',
        episode: 'Episode 2',
        episode_title: 'Episode Title: The Man of Wisdom II',
        overview: 'The Donkeys thought thier minds are hidden but unknowing to them that it goes beyond the physical and that there is one who dwells among them and He knows and sees everything beyond the physical',
        poster_path: '/The_RichMaster_SmallEpisode2.png',
        posterUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SmartsSmallPoster/The_RichMaster_SmallEpisode2.png',
        backdropUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/BigBackdrop/The_RichMaster_BigPoster.jpg',
        adult: false,
        release_date: '20th March, 2022',
        genre_ids: [
        27, 28, 31
      ],
       backdrop_path: '/The_RichMaster_BigPoster.jpg',
       member_required: true,
       free: false,
       belongs_to_collection: null,
       original_language: 'en',
       popularity: null,
       vote_count: '4300',
       video: false,
       vote_average: '8.2',
       homepage: '',
       imdb_id: 'aef091080',
       credit_ids: ['52fe43c4c3a36847f807y890', '52fe43c4c3a36847f808y891', '52fe43c4c3a36847f809y892', 
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f801y893', '52fe43c4c3a36847f802y894', '52fe43c4c3a36847f803y895',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f804y896', '52fe43c4c3a36847f805y897', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806y898',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f801z899'  
       ],
       cast_ids: [
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       production_companies: '3smartsflix',
       production_countries: 'NG',
       runtime: '15',
       spoken_languages: 'en',
       status: 'Upcoming',
       release_type: 3,
       category: 'upcoming',
       upcoming: true,
       now_playing: false,
       category_id: 86,
       tagline: 'Purge Your Mind To House The Goodluck',
       file_path: '/3smarts-photorichmaster-backdrops',
       recomend_id: [5, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       categories: ['UPCOMING'],
       seqNo: 6,
       url: 'the-man-of-wisdom2',
    },

    7: {
        id: 7,
        movieId: 66,
        title: 'The Rich Master & The Donkeys',
        season: 'Season 1',
        episode: 'Episode 3',
        episode_title: 'Episode Title: The Donkeys Folly I',
        overview: 'The Donkeys thought thier minds are hidden but unknowing to them that it goes beyond the physical and that there is one who dwells among them and He knows and sees everything beyond the physical',
        poster_path: '/The_RichMaster_SmallEpisode3.png',
        posterUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SmartsSmallPoster/The_RichMaster_SmallEpisode3.png',
        backdropUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/BigBackdrop/The_RichMaster_BigPoster.jpg',
        adult: false,
        release_date: '3rd April, 2022',
        genre_ids: [
        27, 28, 31
      ],
       backdrop_path: '/The_RichMaster_BigPoster.jpg',
       member_required: true,
       free: false,
       belongs_to_collection: null,
       original_language: 'en',
       popularity: null,
       vote_count: '4300',
       video: false,
       vote_average: '8.2',
       homepage: '',
       imdb_id: 'aef091080',
       credit_ids: ['52fe43c4c3a36847f807y890', '52fe43c4c3a36847f808y891', '52fe43c4c3a36847f809y892', 
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f801y893', '52fe43c4c3a36847f802y894', '52fe43c4c3a36847f803y895',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f804y896', '52fe43c4c3a36847f805y897', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806y898',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f801z899'  
       ],
       cast_ids: [
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       production_companies: '3smartsflix',
       production_countries: 'NG',
       runtime: '15',
       spoken_languages: 'en',
       status: 'Upcoming',
       release_type: 3,
       category_id: 86,
       category: 'upcoming',
       upcoming: true,
       now_playing: false,
       tagline: 'Purge Your Mind To House The Goodluck',
       file_path: '/3smarts-photorichmaster-backdrops',
       recomend_id: [5, 6, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       categories: ['UPCOMING'],
       seqNo: 7,
       url: 'the-donkeys-folly1',
    },

    8: {
        id: 8,
        movieId: 66,
        title: 'The Rich Master & The Donkeys',
        season: 'Season 1',
        episode: 'Episode 4',
        episode_title: 'Episode Title: The Donkeys Folly II',
        overview: 'The Donkeys thought thier minds are hidden but unknowing to them that it goes beyond the physical and that there is one who dwells among them and He knows and sees everything beyond the physical',
        poster_path: '/The_RichMaster_SmallEpisode4.png',
        posterUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SmartsSmallPoster/The_RichMaster_SmallEpisode4.png',
        backdropUrl: 'https://3smartsflix.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/BigBackdrop/The_RichMaster_BigPoster.jpg',
        adult: false,
        release_date: '1st May, 2022',
        genre_ids: [
        27, 28, 31
      ],
       backdrop_path: '/The_RichMaster_BigPoster.jpg',
       member_required: true,
       free: false,
       belongs_to_collection: null,
       original_language: 'en',
       popularity: null,
       vote_count: '4300',
       video: false,
       vote_average: '8.2',
       homepage: '',
       imdb_id: 'aef091080',
       credit_ids: ['52fe43c4c3a36847f807y890', '52fe43c4c3a36847f808y891', '52fe43c4c3a36847f809y892', 
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f801y893', '52fe43c4c3a36847f802y894', '52fe43c4c3a36847f803y895',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f804y896', '52fe43c4c3a36847f805y897', '52fe43c4c3a36847f806y898',
                    '52fe43c4c3a36847f801z899'  
       ],
       cast_ids: [
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       production_companies: '3smartsflix',
       production_countries: 'NG',
       runtime: '15',
       spoken_languages: 'en',
       status: 'Upcoming',
       release_type: 3,
       category_id: 86,
       category: 'upcoming',
       upcoming: true,
       now_playing: false,
       tagline: 'Purge Your Mind To House The Goodluck',
       file_path: '/3smarts-photorichmaster-backdrops',
       recomend_id: [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       categories: ['UPCOMING'],
       seqNo: 8,
       url: 'the-donkeys-folly2',
    },
    
};
```

To getAllMovies I used this code

```js
loadAllMovies(): Observable<MovieModel[]> {
          return this.db.collection(
              'movies',
                  ref=> ref.orderBy("seqNo")
              )
              .snapshotChanges()
              .pipe(
                  map(snaps => convertSnaps<MovieModel>(snaps)),
                  first());
      }
  
  
      getMovieById(movieId: string):Observable<MovieModel | null | undefined> {
          return this.db.collection('movies',
              ref=> ref.where("id", "==", movieId))
              .snapshotChanges()
              .pipe(
                  map(snaps => {
  
                      const movies = convertSnaps<MovieModel>(snaps);
  
                      return movies.length == 1 ? movies[0]: undefined;
                  }),
                  first()
              )
      }

      getMovieDetails(movieId: string):Observable<MovieModel | null | undefined> {
        return this.db.collection('movies',
            ref=> ref.where("id", "==", movieId))
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
                map(snaps => {

                    const movies = convertSnaps<MovieModel>(snaps);

                    return movies.length == 1 ? movies[0]: undefined;
                }),
                first()
            )
    }
```

The issue I am having now is how do I get the followings:

- getPersonDetails
- getPersonCast
- getCastMovie
- getMovieByGenre
- getGenres
- getMovieCredits
- getSingleMoviesVideos

Do I need to getAllPerson before I can access getPersonDetails?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any issues with coding but with Data/code architecture. What issues are you having creating the other methods? Do they gave you any kind of error? Do you have any other collection where the cast/genre ids are referenced? Also, you don't need to post the whole Collection here. With one data sample is enough.

Comment: I am trying to build a custom api for my streaming site, Imbd has their own api which will not work for the custom api hence the need to write my own api services. Let me run it and see if there is any problem. Thanks

Comment: Did you encounter any problem running your custom api?